# Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 JumpList / TaskbarItemInfo example for Windows Forms

Tags: .net-4.0, taskbar

It is my understanding that JumpList implementation using Windows API Code Pack is now depreciated as Microsoft now supports JumpList directly through Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.aspx

I can see that it is possible to set progress etc. to the Taskbar Item in their examples; however I have struggled so much to implement this on a Windows Form.

I had successfully managed to implement JumpList and TaskBarItem progress using Windows API Pack in the past http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/source/browse/trunk/ZScreen/Forms/ZScreenConfigGUI.cs#277 but I want to move away from this dependency and utilise the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 instead.

Your advice is much appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Windows.Application`  is in the presentation framework(`PresentationFramework.dll`) i.e. WPF. It does not exist in Winforms. So use  Windows API Code Pack like here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Jump-List-with-Windows-db005b99

> WPF 4 provides a native support for Jump List. Instead, if we use
>   Windows Forms, we must adopt the Windows API Code Pack, a managed
>   wrapper that allows to access to the Windows API functions. Available
>   on NuGet too, it provides all you need to manage Jump Lists within our
>   Windows Forms Applications.

Another example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events

> It is my understanding that JumpList implementation using Windows API
>   Code Pack is now depreciated

Its not deprecated, its also a part of new .net 4 features but for WPF. For winforms, you will still have to use the pack like mentioned above.